# Why is my query slow in PHP and fast in PHPMYadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following query is optimized with indexes. The time is measured exactly before and after the query execution within PHP and takes sometimes 10 or 20 seconds. I does not seem to depend on the number of rows as sometimes the number of rows is less than 10 and even then the query runs slow. Apart from the query execution as shown below PHP does not do any other operations.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT o.op AS orid,
  (3959 * acos(cos(radians(59.4369583424862))
  * cos(radians(d.latitude)) * cos( radians( d.longitude) -
  radians(24.7535276412964)) + sin(radians(59.4369583424862))
  * sin( radians( d.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
  FROM (
  SELECT * FROM d WHERE
    d.type='rdw' AND d.longitude > 24.4837311595 AND
    d.longitude < 25.0233241231 AND d.latitude > 59.1671618607 AND
    d.latitude < 59.7067548243
  ) AS d
  LEFT JOIN o ON d.destinid = o.destinid
  LEFT JOIN op ON o.operatorid = op.operatorid
  having distance < 30
  ORDER BY distance
) AS t
GROUP BY trajectoperatorid
LIMIT 0, 30
```

This is how the query is executed:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //foreach($rows as $row){
```

A connection to the datase already existed before first time measurement.

When running the same query in phpmyadmin using the SQL_NO_CACHE it takes consistently just 0.06 seconds. Why is exactly the same query slow when it is running within the PHP script?

Below is the php scrip:

```
write_log_file('Start query'.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s') . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8));

$sql1 = "
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT o.op AS orid,
  (3959 * acos(cos(radians(59.4369583424862))
  * cos(radians(d.latitude)) * cos( radians( d.longitude) -
  radians(24.7535276412964)) + sin(radians(59.4369583424862))
  * sin( radians( d.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
  FROM (
  SELECT * FROM d WHERE
    d.type='rdw' AND d.longitude > 24.4837311595 AND
    d.longitude < 25.0233241231 AND d.latitude > 59.1671618607 AND
    d.latitude < 59.7067548243
  ) AS d
  LEFT JOIN o ON d.destinid = o.destinid
  LEFT JOIN op ON o.operatorid = op.operatorid
  having distance < 30
  ORDER BY distance
) AS t
GROUP BY trajectoperatorid
LIMIT 0, 30";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: do you take the measure after `$stmt->execute();` or after `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll` ?

Comment: When you run the query in phpAdmin does phpAdmin change it at all?  Sometime when I run queries it changes them (I assume) in an effort to optimize them

Comment: how are you getting the executed time in php

Comment: Doesn't phpMyAdmin add `LIMIT 0 , 30`?

Comment: I added LIMIT 0,30 also in the PHP script

Comment: The time measurement is befor $sql1='The query above' and after $rows = $stmt ....

Comment: @Sebas see update in question

Comment: The only difference between what you're doing in your PHP code and what's happening in the phpMyAdmin is PDO's emulated prepared statements. So for the sake of trying, add this after making the connection: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`

Comment: This may sound strange but are you connecting to localhost? If so, make sure you connect to your DB as "127.0.0.1" and not "localhost". Trust me, it makes a difference.

Comment: @w00 yes I do connect to localhost, that's weird if that makes a difference will try!

Comment: to compare you have to compare the execution only, not the preparation nor the fetch of the rows. Please give feedback after measuring the .execute statement only.

Comment: @Sebas I checked with time measurement and the fetch doesn't take any time..

Comment: just to be sure, instead of using SQL_NO_CACHE, change a litle any const value on the query

Comment: @LuisSiquot I tried that but didn't make a difference

Comment: could you measure the execution time of `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;` from php the same way you're doing for the original query?

Comment: @Sebas I tried that and it took 0.0008 seconds...

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of SQL to read through!  I'd suggest getting into the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) command in MySQL to track down the issue rather than trying to profile from PHP.

Also have a look at [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html).

Once you understand what's going on inside the database it will likely be easier to tweak the PDO usage if need be.

Comment: well from the database it goes fine, that's the problem

Comment: EXPLAIN is the same in both cases?

Comment: As far as I understood, the exact same query goes really fast from phpmyadmin.

Comment: OK well maybe the exact same query runs differently through PDO based on configuration.  The best way to find out in a hurry is ask MySQL.  Might even be worth running EXPLAIN through PHPMyAdmin as well.

Comment: That is to say who knows which MySQL library PHPMyAdmin is using, just b/c it's PHP doesn't mean it's PDO.

Comment: @quickshiftin I isolated the query in php into a separate script and it runs fine all the time (also using the no cache). So Im thinking it might not be this particular query after all but maybe because the whole script is pretty long with a number of other queries and operations.

Comment: @Sebas From the database it goes indeed fine, when I isolate this piece of script into a separate script it runs fine. The script is pretty long and there are 10 queries like these in it. Something else in the script might be causing this problem.

Comment: @quickshiftin The EXPLAIN gives for both cases identical results.

Comment: Then it's probly something DNS or even another issue as @gmm has suggested.  You might have to breakdown and use tshark to track it down.  one limited but simple test would be to log into the sql server and use `show processlist` to see which queries are running.  start the query off from the pdo client and run `show processlist` until you see the query start to run.  if there is some decent lag (several seconds) before the query even starts, it would def sound like DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put "skip_name_resolve" in MySQL. 10-20 seconds sounds like DNS to me. Is you PHPMyAdmin on the same machine - connecting to localhost? And you PHP using IP connection?

Comment: @gmm Isn't skip_name_resolve for making the database connection? The connection was already made and is outside of the time measurement. I make the connection once and then do a couple of queries.